# Getting a Unicode code point ("character") by name

Tags: perl, unicode

Perl makes it very convenient to get some symbol.

```
$ perl -CO -E 'say "\N{FAMILY}"'
```

Is there a way to evaluate the symbol with `"\N{}"` via interpolation? Something similar to:

```
perl -CO -E 'my $what = "FAMILY"; say "\N{$what}"'
```

(which does not work, but gives you the flavour).

Besides feasibility, is there any drawback or possible threat in such evaluation? E.g. say the `$what` string is user-defined, I would never `eval $what`. Would I `\N{$what}` safely?

### Ops...

After getting the answers, I noticed how this information clearly stated in `perlunicook`. Sorry for the lack of RTFM. I guess this is a good thing to have on stackoverflow anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `vianame` function from [charnames](http://p3rl.org/charnames):

```
perl -CO -Mcharnames=:full -wE 'say chr charnames::vianame("PILE OF POO")'
```

Comment: Interesting choice of example.

Comment: This guy made my day

Comment: That's worth it, just for the example.

Answer (score 5):

```
use charnames ();
my $what = "FAMILY";
say charnames::string_vianame($what);
```